# passport add paramaters to request with nestjs javascript

Tags: javascript, nestjs, passport.js

I'm doing an application and I'm using "NestJS" for the back.

In my application, I have a button that allows the user to connect his Spotify account (using passport).

For the moment, when the user clicks on the button, I get the access token but I can't stock it for now.

My problem is that I have no idea of how to tell my back which user clicked on the button, and how to stock the user id somewhere until I have the token. Here is my code :

In my front, I just have a button that redirects to my back :

```
const handleSpotifyButton = () => {
  window.location.href = "http://localhost:8080/auth/spotify";
};
```

I guess that I can pass an extra parameter like this :

```
window.location.href = "http://localhost:8080/auth/spotify?userId=${userId}";
```

But then, I don't know how to use it in my back. Here is my controller :

```js
import { SpotifyAuthGuard } from "./spotify-auth.guard";
import { Controller, Get, Request, UseGuards } from "@nestjs/common";
import { SpotifyService } from "./spotify-auth.service";
import { Redirect } from "@nestjs/common";

@Controller("auth")
export class SpotifyController {
  constructor(private spotifyService: SpotifyService) {}

  @Get("spotify")
  @UseGuards(SpotifyAuthGuard)
  async spotifyAuth() {}

  @Get("spotify-redirect")
  @Redirect("http://localhost:8081")
  @UseGuards(SpotifyAuthGuard)
  spotifyAuthRedirect(@Request() req) {
    this.spotifyService.spotifyLogin(req);
  }
}
```

Here I could get the parameter in the route "spotify", but then I don't really know how it works to open the spotify authorization window.

The ideal would be to get it in my service, where I print the token, so I could just add it in my database from here :

```js
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";

@Injectable()
export class SpotifyService {
  async spotifyLogin(req): Promise<string> {
    if (!req.user) {
      return "No user from spotify";
    }
    const spotifyUser = req.user;
    console.log(spotifyUser.accessToken);
    return spotifyUser;
  }
}
```

Here is my guard :

```js
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { ConfigService } from "@nestjs/config";
import { AuthGuard } from "@nestjs/passport";

@Injectable()
export class SpotifyAuthGuard extends AuthGuard("spotify") {
  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {
    super({
      accessType: "offline",
    });
  }
}
```

My module :

```js
import { SpotifyAuthStrategy } from "./spotify-auth.strategy";
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { SpotifyController } from "./spotify-auth.controller";
import { SpotifyService } from "./spotify-auth.service";
import { ConfigModule } from "@nestjs/config";

@Module({
  imports: [ConfigModule.forRoot()],
  controllers: [SpotifyController],
  providers: [SpotifyService, SpotifyAuthStrategy],
})
export class SpotifyAuthModule {}
```

And my strategy :

```js
import { PassportStrategy } from "@nestjs/passport";
import { Strategy, VerifyCallback, Profile } from "passport-spotify";
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";

@Injectable()
export class SpotifyAuthStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, "spotify") {
  constructor() {
    super({
      clientID: "myClientId",
      clientSecret: "myClientSecret",
      callbackURL: "http://localhost:8080/auth/spotify-redirect",
      scope: ["user-library-read", "user-library-modify"],
    });
  }

  async validate(
    accessToken: string,
    refreshToken: string,
    profile: Profile,
    done: VerifyCallback,
  ): Promise<any> {
    try {
      const { id, displayName, emails } = profile;

      const user = {
        id,
        displayName,
        email: emails ? emails[0].value : null,
        accessToken,
        refreshToken,
      };

      done(null, user);
    } catch (error) {
      done(error, null);
    }
  }
}
```

Ask me if you need more informations about my code

Thanks